# Jgit 4.11 ocassionally staging all changes to commit instead of provided file pattern

Tags: java, git, repository, jsch, jgit

I am pushing the changes through following code:

```
String folderPath = "files/filestoPush/"; String AddPattern = ""; 

List<String> listFiles =new ArrayList<>(); listFiles. add("file1");
AddPattern = folderPath + listFiles.get(0) + ".java" ;
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/.git");
final Git git = new Git(localRepo);
git.add().addFilepattern(AddPattern).call();


String commitid =(git.commit().setMessage("Committed on : " + new Date()).call().getName()).toString();
PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull();


pullCmd.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {

    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
    }
});
pullCmd.call();
Iterable<PushResult> prs = git.push().setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {

    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
    }
}).call();
```

This code is occasionally adding all changes to commit instead of only the addfilepattern provided. A single filename's relative path is being provided in this addfilepattern.

Comment: What has the `pull` and `push` code to do with adding more changes than wanted?

Comment: Could you post the code that computes `AddPattern`? (BTW variables in Java start with lowercase letters)

Comment: String folderPath = "files/filestoPush/";
String AddPattern = ""; List<String> listFiles =new ArrayList<>(); listFiles. add("file1");
AddPattern = folderPath + listFiles.get(0) + ".java" ;

Comment: Why don't you edit the question? That's much easier to read.